# sum values from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sum

Using PHP, I can find the `productId` in the first table:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT productId FROM boughtProducts WHERE userid = :username");
$stmt->execute(array(':username' => $_SESSION['username']));
$productId = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

I also have a columns with values in variables like the following:

```
$productId["0"]["productId"] & $productId["1"]["productId"]...
```

In the variables above I only get IDs where I must find my values in second table.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT price FROM products WHERE id = :productid");
$stmt->execute(array(':productid' => $productId["0"]["productId"]));
$price = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This returns all numbers, which I want to SUM and store in a variable.  How can I achieve this?
I want to SUM price for all products which are bought by `userid`.

Comment: `userid = :username` are you sure about that ?

Comment: *"I want to SUM"* - Appropriately enough, `SUM()`. Now go try something ;-) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines might work:

```
SELECT SUM(products.price) FROM boughtProducts, products WHERE boughtProducts.userid = :username and products.id = boughtProducts.productId
```

Read something about the `JOIN` keyword (I'm using an **implicit join** in my example)... also get yourself acquainted with the concept of **foreign keys**.

Good luck!

Comment: Thx so much! I know little bit more about sql now!